# Callback for Google Play Ads (android.googleAdUnitId or ios.googleAdUnitId build hints)

Tags: callback, admob, codenameone, banner

My CodenameOne app works perfectly when using the **android.googleAdUnitId** or **ios.googleAdUnitId** *build hints* in order to show the **Admob Ads banner** at the bottom. However, I would like to give some coins/diamonds as rewards when users click on the bottom Ads banner. How can I do this? Is it possible for the main class to handle this by implementing the **AdsListener interface** like the https://github.com/chen-fishbein/admobfullscreen-codenameone supports (or at least the main class should implement a **special interface** which has the **onAdLeftApplication()** function only?)

Shai, Chen, anyone, do you have any advice?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to adjust the banner behavior, if you want to reward the user use full screen ads, there are quite a few full screen ads providers with a CodenameOne integration see these:
https://github.com/chen-fishbein/flurry-codenameone , https://github.com/chen-fishbein/startapp-codenameone , https://github.com/amiga/aerserv-codenameone